# How to get integer list from a string but not integer list?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to create an integer list from the string list called a. The list I want to create is shown in the integer list called b.

```
a = ["ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ab","ab"]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]
```

I've tried that solution but it takes long time for thousands of data.

```
a = ["ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ab","ab"]
b = list(set(a))
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] in b:
        a[i] = b.index(a[i])+1
print(a)
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the rules for converting string value to integers? Are there only 4 possible string values or are there more?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were your results?

Comment: The program reads from a txt file, that is why there may be thousands.I plan to import the received values ​​into numpy array and get numpy output, string values are unusefull in this case. @mike

Comment: So you just want to assign a unique number to each different string? Create a dictionary with the strings as keys. When you get a string that's not in the dictionary, increment a counter and add it to the dictionary.

Comment: Then append the dictionary value onto `b`

Comment: @kukuro Welcome to Stackoverflow. However, did you read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? Your question needs more focus.

Comment: @Anderson I've edited.

Comment: @kukuro that's fine but what is the rule creating the integers? Is is just based on the first unique count of each string value in the list?

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes, I think it should be enough. Actually I was waiting for a faster solution, I don't know if there is a function for this task.

Comment: @kukuro how long is it currently taking and how long do you want it to take?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Input array of strings.
a = ["ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ab","ab"]

d = {}
counter = 0
b = []
for item in a:
    if item not in d:
        counter += 1
        d[item] = counter
    b.append(d[item])

>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1]
```

Comment: It's a similar way with mine and it will take long time I guess, I'll try and inform you.

Comment: Our solutions are very different. Your `if a[i] in b` call is expensive given that `b` has been converted to a list.  The indexing call is expensive as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see that by applying your code, it takes really less time than mine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on the values provide in you question you can gather the unique values to a list and then use the index of the unique list to provide the numbers for each value to get the expected output.

```
a = ["ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ab", "ab"]
unique_list = []
b = []

for value in a:
    if value not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(value)

for value in a:
    for ndex, unique_value in enumerate(unique_list):
        if value == unique_value:
            b.append(ndex+1)
            break

print(b)
```

Results:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1]
```

That said there is no way to know for sure what your string values translate to without more context in your question.

UPDATE:

Based on questions in the comments I also tested this with a set and ran a new random set of 40,000 values 10 times for `set()` and 10 times for `list`. The list appears to run faster unless I am doing something wrong here.

```
import time
import random

times_for_set = []
times_for_list = []
times_for_dict = []

def run_comparison_set():
    a = []
    for _ in range(40000):
        x = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        y = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        a.append('{}{}'.format(x, y))

    unique_list = set(a)
    b = []

    start_time = time.time()
    for value in a:
        for ndex, unique_value in enumerate(unique_list):
            if value == unique_value:
                b.append(ndex+1)
                break
    times_for_set.append(time.time() - start_time)


def run_comparison_list():
    a = []
    for _ in range(40000):
        x = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        y = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        a.append('{}{}'.format(x, y))

    unique_list = []
    b = []
    for value in a:
        if value not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(value)
    start_time = time.time()
    for value in a:
        for ndex, unique_value in enumerate(unique_list):
            if value == unique_value:
                b.append(ndex + 1)
                break
    times_for_list.append(time.time() - start_time)


def run_comparison_dict():
    a = []
    for _ in range(40000):
        x = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        y = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        a.append('{}{}'.format(x, y))

    counter = 0
    d = {}
    b = []
    start_time = time.time()
    for item in a:
        if item not in d:
            counter += 1
            d[item] = counter
        b.append(d[item])
    times_for_dict.append(time.time() - start_time)


for i in range(10):
    run_comparison_set()
    run_comparison_list()
    run_comparison_dict()

print('Average time for set: ', sum(times_for_set) / len(times_for_set))
print('Average time for list: ', sum(times_for_list) / len(times_for_list))
print('Average time for dict: ', sum(times_for_dict) / len(times_for_dict))
```

Results:

```
Average time for set:  0.8128192901611329
Average time for list:  0.6368690490722656
Average time for dict:  0.00530548095703125
```

So it appears that list and set are much slower than a dict.

Comment: Won't using a dictionary be faster?

Comment: @HarshalParekh Not sure. But a dictionary is a more complex data structure than a list and takes up more resources so maybe not.

Comment: You should absolutely prefer a set or dictionary to a list for inclusion checking.  For a tiny example it would make that much of a difference, but if your unique list grows large, you are looking at a large O(n) vs O(1) for lookup.

Comment: @user3483203 I just tested with 4000 random values and it took 0.16 sec to run. Seams fast enough to me. Tested with 40,000 values and it only took 1.44 sec.

Comment: Did you time it with a set instead of a list?  What was the difference?

Comment: @user3483203 using `unique_list = set(a)` the resulting time was 1.59 sec. After running it a few time the range from 1.57 to 1.68.

Comment: That seems off.. On my machine, your solution is over 100x slower than Alexanders for a size of 4000.

Comment: @user3483203 could it be a version difference issue? What version of python do you have?

Comment: @user3483203 I ran a set of 10 for both `set` and `list`  My list ran faster. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I have updated my post to show my test code.

Comment: @user3483203 added the dict comparison to my test. You are correct. Dict is way faster but set seams slower.

Comment: Your set code isn't right.  It has the same inclusion checking `if el in unique_set` as a dictionary, you are still using an O(n^2) algorithm instead of O(n)

Comment: @user3483203 I guess I need to look into the different algorithm's then. I do not know what exactly I should be doing with set at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ab","ab"]
from itertools import count
counter = count(1)
a_dict = dict()
b = []
for elem in a:
    a_dict[elem] = a_dict.get(elem, next(counter))
    b.append(a_dict[elem])

print(b)
```

Outputs:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1]

Just keeping track of which ones have been seen, and their respective numbers.  If not seen, it grabs the next number on the counter.